# What does the script tag do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Yo everyone. I am Admin's relative. Just a beginner in javascript. I would like to ask what is the following line, its purpose, what it does, where you put it and so on. My question might be simple but it would be really much appreciated if anyone can give good explanation to this question.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is meant to import a script... JQuery in the instance from the googleapis website

Comment: I find it interesting to see the extensive answers on a one-line answer. Reputation over helping? (not you Admin Relative)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, this loading [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/) library from the CDN.

1. **what is the following line**

   This will include `jQuery` library on your page
2. **its purpose, what it does**

   As you might have read [`jQuery Tag WiKi`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) on SO,

   > jQuery (Core) is a cross-browser JavaScript library (created by John Resig) which provides abstractions for common client-side tasks such as DOM traversal, DOM manipulation, event handling, animation and Ajax.

   You might want to visit [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/) homepage.

   > jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers. If you're new to jQuery, we recommend that you check out the [**jQuery Learning Center**](http://learn.jquery.com/).
3. **where you put it**

   You can put this in `head` or at the end of `body` tag. You just need to add this before any `jQuery` plugin.

**I'll highly recommend you to take this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/30-days-to-learn-jquery).**

Answer (score 1):

This line loads jQuery, a javascript library (see http://jquery.com for details on jQuery), in to your page. It is customary to put it in the `<head>` tag of your page, and as you're just beginning I would recommend that.

There are some cases, however, where you want to optimize your page load time and it may be better to put it at the end of the `<bod>` tag, right before `</body>`. But for now I'd put it in the `<head>`.

The `src` tells the script tag where to load the file from. In this case, it's from a CDN (content delivery network) which hosts the files, and is used for slightly faster download times (not something you'll need to worry about at this point).

And welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

This line is usually placed in the header section of a webpage, but can always be placed anywhere depending on your need.

What the code does is it loads the javascript codes found at the link, onto the page.
This avoids having lengthy javascript codes within your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

It is a link to an external script. It basically copies and pastes the code from that location into the file where you write it. You usually put it at the top of the file where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

`<script>`  tag is used for importing a script. (can be java script or vbscript.)

jQuery is a framework for JavaScript.

So the line you mentioned is to invoke the jQuery script code in your code.

Now, you can do it in two ways, either download it, and then give the src, or use it from cdn. The src in this line is from the CDN. For more details of how to use jQuery, the minimal you can read is: [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp).

Answer (score 0):

It will load the content of the external script file. In this way you can better organise your code and reuse code libraries in different projects.
It is best practise to load the script files last in order for the browser to load the html first.